# SQL Server need to find all records for same user across multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of tables and a list of users.  I need to find all of the occurrences of each user that happen to occur in every table in that is in the list.  I need to search each table for one user ID at a time.  I have 310,000 users to search for and 400 tables to search through.  Each User needs to be searched for on each table.  I'm not quite sure about the best way to go about this as I don't know how I could loop through either list to find all the records for each user.

Summary:
310,000 users
400 tables
need to find how many records each user has in every table.

Comment: Why would you want to use a loop for this? You should instead write a set based query, likely with some aggregation.

Comment: If these tables have effectively the same structure it seems like a serious mistake in the schema design.

Comment: @SeanLange could you provide a link for a possible walkthrough of a based query with aggregation?

Comment: You should explain how the expected result has to look like. For looping over all tables of a database you could use sp_MSforeachtable @command1="select count(*) from ?"

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn what do you mean the same structure?  Because each table is different in what columns they have but all of them have a user ID foreign key and I need to find all the records that have their user ID in that column on each table if that makes sense.

Comment: @IngoB sorry I need to get a simple list of how many records each user has in total across these multiple tables because the end result is each of those records is going to be deleted so I just to be aware of how many records are going to be effected

Comment: You do realize this is going to be stupidly slow right? There is no way to do that really fast. You likely need to select from your users table and then left join all 400 tables. This truly sounds like you are trying to look for some information that probably isn't really needed.

Comment: Does the column with the ID in ***always*** have the same name? It's not called `ID` in some tables, `UserID` in others, `PersonID` in another, etc, etc.

Comment: @SeanLange yes I realize it's going to be slow but it doesn't need to be fast.  We do need the data because we need to delete this legacy data from the database because of my company's data retention policy, these user records are past the point that we need to keep their records so we need to find all the records they have across the database and remove them

Comment: @Larnu to my knowledge all of the columns are the same name, there might be a few outliers but I can deal with that if that causes a problem later as long as I can get the majority of tables done

Comment: Sounds like you should just set cascade options on your foreign keys, then delete the parent rows

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete stab in the dark, but this might be what you are after. This **assumes** you are using a fully supported version of SQL Server (as you haven't stated otherwise); if not you'll need to use the old `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) method for string aggregation.

```sql
DECLARE @ColumnName sysname = N'YourColumnName',
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10),
        @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(N'SELECT N' + QUOTENAME(t.[name],'''') + N' AS TableName,' + @CRLF +
                         N'       ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + N',' +@CRLF +
                         N'       COUNT(*) AS RowsInTable' + @CRLF +
                         N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N';',@CRLF)
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.[name] IN (SELECT YT.TableName
                   FROM dbo.YourTableOfTables YT)
  AND c.[name] = @ColumnName;

CREATE TABLE #UserRowCounts (TableName sysname,
                             UserID int, --Guessed data type
                             RowsInTable int);

INSERT INTO #UserRowCounts
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;

SELECT TableName,
       UserID,
       RowsInTable
FROM #UserRowCounts URC
WHERE URC.UserID IN (SELECT YT.UserID
                     FROM dbo.YourTableOfUsers)
ORDER BY UserID,
         TableName;
```

As mentioned in the comments, this probably won't be quick; but then you are counting the rows from 400~ tables in a single batch so you shouldn't expect it to be.

Comment: I am using a fully supported/activated version of SQL Server